# trigger function on "gotoCurrent" with jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I very happy using the datepicker from jQuery UI.

and the onSelect: function... works perfectly.

But:

How do I go about triggering a function when I click the "gotoCurrent"-button beneath the calendar. As far as I can see I can only trigger on onSelect by default, so I guess what I need to do is actually extend the functionality of datepicker?

Any hints on what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#datepicker button.ui-datepicker-current").attr("onclick", "");
    $("#datepicker button.ui-datepicker-current").click(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
```

This worked. If anyone has a more beautiful solution I'd be happy to see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ gotoCurrent: function(){...}; });
```

I believe that will work.  If I understood you correctly.

Alternatively:

```
$('ui-datepicker-current').click(function(){
     some function

});
```